# Add UIWebView to NavigationViewController

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I want to add a UIWebView to the view of my NavigationViewController. Here is what I am doing,

In my NavigationViewController.h:

```
@interface NavViewController : UINavigationController {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView; 
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

In the implementation file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:req];
}
```

And in the IB, I linked the webView to the outlet, the resource file has been added. However, when I run the app, it says "debugging terminated", and return to Home. Any help?

---

All right, I have fixed this. Thanks.

Comment: searchView is it webview

Comment: It's a typo, sorry, now fixed.

Comment: ok .try clear all targets and remove build and run it. and put break point at viewDidload...then you get what exactly problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the name of the HTML file. Is it named exactly as test.html??